# No puedo instalar el plugin subversive en eclipse oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse

Intento instalar el plugin subversive en la nueva versión de eclipse (oxygen) y me aparece el siguiente error.

> ```
> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
> Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
> If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or 
> install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update 
> site.
> If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at:
> Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
> ```

Cuando intento agregar el conector, escojo el SVN Kit y no hace absolutamente nada.

Comment: Yo tampoco lo he conseguido. Al final voy a optar por probar con Subeclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que ya habrás instalado el plugin.

Sólo tienes que seguir los siguientes pasos:

> - Help -> Install New Software
> - Elegir "Update Site -
> - Direccion web: http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/
> - Instalar: "Subversive SVN Connectors" and "SVNKit 1.8.14 Implementation"
> - Reiniciar

```
Versión inglesa
```

> - Install Subversive an restart Eclipse as usual
> - Try to install the SVNkit connector in Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> SVN Connector
> - This fails
> - Not sure if a restart was needed here
> - After that open Help -> Install New Software
> - Choose "Update Site - http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/"
> - Install "Subversive SVN Connectors" and "SVNKit 1.8.14 Implementation" from there

Puedes encontrar más información sobre el problema en esta página:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518033

Comment: ¿Tendrán el enlace actualizado para el conector del SVN para Eclipse Oxygen? Porque ese que compartieron en la respuesta ya no existe y manda un error 404.